# Is my plan for mounting a child safety gate feasible?

Tags: woodworking, gates

As seen in picture below, this sliding kitchen door is not long enough in width. Red arrows indicate how much it falls short.

[image]

I am thinking of drilling four holes and mounting with screws instead. Red circles indicate where screws are to be drilled in.

[image]

Then I will raise it up to ensure it is not touching the floor therefore have enough space to allow sliding. Red arrows indicate where I will hold it up.

[image]

Is my approach feasible?

Comment: That type of gate functions by swinging on the hinges, not sliding. The slide feature is just so that you can fit your opening. You'll soon get tired of sliding it to get in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metal brackets near the points of your red arrows are intended to be mounted to the wall and act as hinges for the entire gate. I would turn them 90° to the gate and mount them to the green cabinet where you had planned on using the screws. This will allow the gate to swing in one direction at least. You may not be able to swing it into the kitchen as it will bind. At least the gate will function as it was designed.